# How can i find the index of parent clicking child

Tags: jquery

On clicking child, I want to know the parent index no. Example, there is a div with 3 ul's when I click on each ul's child, it should show the parent index no. of it's parent. How can I get this?

jQuery:

```
$('.opSection').on('click','li',function(){

    var num = $(this).parent('ul').index();

    alert(num);

    //alert(chartData.Indices[$(this).index()][$(this).index()]);

    })
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="opSection">//parent of all
<dl><dd>
        <ul class="selectGroup" title='allIndia' data-select='1'>
            <li data-index="123" class="c_on">All India</li> // when i click any of li i need 0
        </ul>

        <ul class="selectGroup" title='allIndia' data-select='1'>
            <li data-index="123" class="c_on">All India</li> // when i click this, i need 1
        </ul>
</dd></dl>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.opSection').on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().index();
});
```

**Note** I've used event delegation to improve performance when handling events for multiple elements.

The important parts here is [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to select the `ul`, and then [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index), which, when passed with no parameters, returns it's position relative to its sibling elements.

**EDIT** As you've said in your comment that your markup isn't the same as what you posted in the question, try the following instead:

```
$('.opSection').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    $(e.delegateTarget).find('.selectGroup').index(this.parentNode);
});
```

`$(e.delegateTarget)` is the same (but faster) than `$('.opSection')`. We then search all descendants ([`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find)) for all the `<ul />`'s, and use the same `index()` method to find the position of the one we clicked.

Comment: it give only 0 always. the UL is not direct children of ('.opSection'), it has no.of children, one of the children is UL